# 17.04 can't get into desktop environment

Tags: kubuntu, 17.04, plasma

Just upgraded from 16.10 to 17.04 and when it restarted it went into plasma as expected but I wanted to check out unity 8 so I logged out and changed to unity. The screen went black. I tried restarting but I believe it logins to the last de by default so it kept going from the boot screen to a black screen.

I tried ctrl-alt-1 and got to the cli but now I still can't get back to plasma or anything else that works. sudo startx brings me to a black screen with a cross hair for a curser. Here I can access guake terminal emlutor but nothing else. I created a script early that restarts the plasma desktop on start up since it would need to be restarted whenever I shut my computer and opened it again. When I ran that in the emulator the plasma desktop comes up but I'm limited in what I can do. When I try to open most applications I get an error saying "could not find the program 'program-name'". And when I try to logout nothing happens.

I do have access to my file manager and settings though but haven't been able to find a solution using either of those. Changing default login settings isn't doing anything.

Any ideas how to get back to a normal session?

Comment: What happens if you try to go back to the desktop with ctrl-alt-f7?

Comment: The screen freezes until I go back to ctrl-alt-f1 or nothing if I do it first thing after boot.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the same behaviour with Kubuntu 17.04. I change to terminal 1 with ctrl+alt+1 and issue
         sudo /etc/init.d/sddm status
gives "running".
If I do 
         sudo /etc/init.d/sddm stop
it waits for a while, trying to stop the process, then returns to terminal 7 with the same blank screen. It perhaps respawns sddm. 
If I kill sddm thread with kill -9 xxxx xxxx, then also same issue.
If I do
         startx
it takes me to a black screen with the kde default mouse pointer, but frozen.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the default Desktop Environment (DE) by running the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure XXX` where XXX is your active DE whether it be `sddm`, `lightdm`, `gdm3` etc. and select your preferred DE (I would recommend `sddm` (since you are using the KDE DE) or `lightdm` which both allows you to select the whichever session (Unity, Plasma, GNOME etc.) you would like to start.